# Couchbase : change admin port 9100 indexer_admin_port

Tags: docker, port, couchbase, indexer

I would like to change the admin port 9100 to 19100 but I was not able to do it.

So I am running 2 couchbase servers community 7 using docker (clustering - I mean I am using two servers and on each server, a docker with couchbase is running) and I mounted a volume to change the static_config by adding {indexer_admin_port, 9100}. but after killing/removing the container. The servers are still listening on port 9100 and in the indexer logs, it shows servers are still trying to connect on 9100…

So Any idea on how to change the 9100 port to 19100?

Thanks

Note : I found this documentation
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/install-ports.html but it didnt work..

Answer (score 0):

Within Docker, can't you just re-map the ports within Docker?  If you want to change which address the server actually listens on, I believe you'll want to use Alternate Addresses: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/connectivity.html#assigning-alternate-addresses